# How to get Payment ID after Checkout PayPal

Tags: c#, paypal

I want to get paypal payment id, after payment checkout aproval, to execute the payment but i don't know how to do it?

That payment id is to be used in here:

```
pymnt = new Payment();
pymnt.id = **PAYMENT_ID**; 
PaymentExecution pymntExecution = new PaymentExecution();
pymntExecution.payer_id = context.Request.Params["PayerID"];
Payment executedPayment = pymnt.Execute(apiContext, pymntExecution);
context.Response.Write(JObject.Parse(executedPayment.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Formatting.Indented));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

In last they have

> When the user approves the payment, PayPal redirects the user to the return_url that was specified when the payment was created. A payer ID is appended to the return URL, as PayerID:
>
> http://?token=EC-60U79048BN7719609&PayerID=7E7MGXCWTTKK2
>
> The token value appended to the return URL is not needed when you execute the payment.
>
> To execute the payment after the user’s approval, make a /payment/execute/ call. In the body >of the request, use the payer_id value that was appended to the return URL. In the >header, use the access token that you used when you created the payment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the paypal documentation isn't clear about this. But you can do something simple to resolve your problem passing the PaymentID through a parameter in your return url.

Like this: `return_url = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/paypal/success/?paymentID=PAY-1234567'`

When the Paypal redirect to your site, then, it will return the paymentID together with the other parameters.

Comment: i can't pass that parameter, because that is generated after i submit checkout aproval, this is pay in paypal, then in return he brings PayerID and Token